# Check two string have same month and year values

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have two variables BrkPt and TestDate. BrkPt has value 3/05/2014 and TesDate has value 201405. I need to check if these two values are same( which is yes in this case - year 2014 and month 05). Can someone help me to proceed with this?

```
For GateChartRowCount = 15 To GateChartLastRow
Worksheets("Gate Chart").Activate
            GateChartValueToFind = Cells(GateChartRowCount, 1).Value
        If (GateChartValueToFind = vbNullString) Then GoTo lblDoneWithValueToFind:
            Worksheets("Reference").Activate
            RefRowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(10), GateChartValueToFind)
            If (RefRowCount <> 0) Then
                    RefRowForData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(GateChartValueToFind, Columns(10), 0)
                    BrkPt = Worksheets("Reference").Cells(RefRowForData, 11)
            End If

            For GateChartColumnCount = 2 To GateChartLastColumn - 3
            Worksheets("Gate Chart").Activate
            TestDate = Worksheets("Gate Chart").Cells(14, GateChartColumnCount)
            TestDateConverted = CDate(TestDate)
            BrkPt = Format(BrkPt, "mmyyyy")
            BrkPt = CDate(BrkPt)
                If TestDateConverted = BrkPt Then
                    Worksheets("Gate Chart").Cells(GateChartRowCount, GateChartColumnCount + 1) = "YES"
                End If
            Next GateChartColumnCount

lblDoneWithValueToFind:
Next GateChartRowCount
```

Comment: Can you show me your code? or what have you done so far?

Comment: I have pasted the code along with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure have fixed format that BrkPt and TestDate, you can use the following code:

```
Sub TRY()

BrkPt = "3/05/2014"
TestDateConverted = "201405"

    BrkPt = "3/05/2014"
    Y = Right(BrkPt, 4)
    M = Mid(BrkPt, 3, 2)
    D = Left(BrkPt, 1)

    BrkPt = Format(DateSerial(Y, M, D), "MMYYYY")

    TestDateConverted = "201405"
    Y = Left(TestDateConverted, 4)
    M = Mid(TestDateConverted, 5, 2)


    TestDateConverted = Format(DateSerial(Y, M, D), "MMYYYY")

    If BrkPt = TestDateConverted Then
        MsgBox "Both Matches"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If `TestDate` is a string of the type "YYYYMM" and `BrkPt` is a DateTime value, then you might use a function to make your evaluation:

```
Public Function IsTheSame(ByVal BrkPt As Date, ByVal TestDate As String) As Boolean
    Dim str1 As String: str1 = Year(BrkPt) & Month(BrkPt)
    If str1 = TestDate Then
         IsTheSame = True
    Else
         IsTheSame = False
    End If    
End Function
```

So you will be able to call the function and make your comparison, the function will answer your question "are the two dates with the same month and year?" by just telling you "True" or "False".

Comment: This is great. Let me try this idea and get back if I have any issues.